# Let $S$ be the set consisting of all those real n numbers that can be written as $p-2a$

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus

Let $S$ be the set consisting of all those real n numbers that can be written as $p-2a$ where $p$ & $a$ are the perimeter and area of a right-triangle having base length 1. Then $S$ is

a) $(2,\infty)$

b)$(1,\infty)$

c)$(0,\infty)$

Now, on noticing the question, the first triangle that comes to mind is the triangle with side lengths $1, 1$ and $\sqrt2$.
This satisfies the condition $p-2a$ to point to option (a) (Option (a) is supposed to be the correct answer)
[$p-2a=1+1+\sqrt2-2(\frac{1}2(1)(1))$]

However,
if we take the right angle triangle with side lengths $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ and $1$, we find that these values when substituted in the given condition, point to option (b)

[$p-2a= \frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+1 - 2(\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}))$
Here, they hypotenuse is the base.]

Secondly, I came up with the solution just by guessing. Is there a systematic way to approach it?

What is wrong in the $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ and $1$, triangle that I have assumed?

Comment: While I think it is a good idea to use canonical triangles to try and understand the minimum of the desired range, it is not clear to me why $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ,1$ was chosen. Having said that, this triangle doesn't qualify because $1$ is not the base of this right-angled triangle : it is the hypotenuse. I believe the base refers to any side which is not a hypotenuse. As for the question itself : call $h$ as the other non-hypotenuse side. Then , $p = 1 + h + \sqrt{1+h^2}$ and $a = \frac{h}{2}$ so $2a = h$. From here, can you continue? Note that $h$ can be anything positive

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Firstly, are you saying that a base always (in all questions) means someting that is not the hypo? I would have not asked if the options did not include $(0,\infty)$ & $(1,\infty)$
And secondly, thanks for that second clue. That's enough.

Comment: Precisely : I don't think that the base can be the largest side of the triangle (in terms of terminology : obviously you can rotate a triangle so that every side becomes it's "bottom side" and hence base) : it's common to consider the base of a right angled triangle as one of the non-hypotenuse sides. Why? Roughly speaking, we use right-angled triangles to model slopes and geological features rising upward from the ground. In such a situation, the right-angle is the ground's angle with the building : so the base, which is the ground, is a non-hypotenuse of the triangle.

Comment: That's never really explained in school, so perhaps it's a nice takeaway. It was good to be of help : if you get the answer you can post a self-answer and call me, I may correct you or vote up etc. based on your answer.

Comment: Now that makes sense! Thanks

Comment: Sure, it was good to be able to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the base of the triangle is one of the non-hypotenuse sides. Slopes are defined to be the fraction $\frac{rise}{run}$. Add to the Teresa Lisbon's comment. In such cases, the base is clearly defined as a side that is NOT the hypotenuse.

You can always assume common variables such as $h$, $b$ for questions related to triangles. Again, as Teresa Lisbon has pointed that by the simple use of the Pythagoras theorem, $1+h+\sqrt{1+h^2}$ is the perimeter and $a=\frac{1}{2}(1)(h).$
This gives $2a=h$

Substituting values in the expression given in the question, $p-2a = 1+h+\sqrt{1+h^2} - h \implies p-2a = 1+\sqrt{1+h^2}$

The smallest right triangle with base $b=1$ has height $h=$(some +ve $h$)
And hence,
the min value of $p-2a = 1+\sqrt1$ which clearly points to the first option.
($h$ can be any positive real number)

Comment: I am not sure that the smallest triangle with base $b$ needs to have height $h=1$. This was actually a bit of a confusing point for me. Imagine a very, very gradual slope for example. Couldn't it happen that the height $h$ is smaller than the base $b$? So we would start from $h$ being as close to $0$ as possible, so we get $1 + \sqrt{1} = 2$ as the smallest possible value. But otherwise, I'm great with the answer.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I see. I got your point. Lets assume you are correct. After you have written the expression,  the figure no longer remains a triangle. Secondly, if you still insist then that would clearly imply that $(2,\infty)$ is the wrong answer. Is it correct to assume that $h$ is close to 0 but not take $1+\sqrt1=2$ as the min value?

Comment: If $h$ is close to zero, then $p-2a = 1+\sqrt{1+h^2}$ is close to $2$, isn't it? So the answer would still be $1+1 =2$, because if I make $h$ as small as required, I can make $1+\sqrt{1+h^2}$ as close to $2$ as required. I think $h$ can be anything , for example the height $h$ could be anything positive , imagine pressing [this triangle from the top](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.splashlearn.com%2Fmath-vocabulary%2Fgeometry%2Fright-triangle&psig=AOvVaw3PR98hADzAD6u3Xrm0fP63&ust=1625985563944000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAoQjRxqFwoTCJjl0sPy1_ECFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD).

Comment: But I cannot go below $2$ : for example, if $1+\sqrt{1+h^2} = 1.9$ then $\sqrt{1+h^2} = 0.9$ so $1+h^2 = 0.81$. But that means that $h^2 = -0.19$, and the square of a real number can never be negative. So thankfully, the answer $(2,\infty)$ still works out.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Correct. That's what I wanted. $h$ can be anything positive. Not zero.

Comment: Then you've got the correct answer!